# Conditional within align environment not resolving

Tags: align, conditionals, matrices

I try to use a shortcut for setting matrices with different brackets.
My solution works fine in displaymath and equation environments.
However, as soon as I try to use it within align, there is an error coming up.

Does anyone know a solution where I can still use my definition within align?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Mtrx}[2][1]{
    \ifx0#1
        \begin{matrix}  #2 \end{matrix}
    \else\ifx1#1
        \begin{bmatrix}  #2 \end{bmatrix}
    \else\ifx2#1
        \begin{pmatrix}  #2 \end{pmatrix}
    \fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}
% everything as expected here:
\begin{equation}
    \Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D} = \Mtrx[1]{c\\d}
\end{equation}

% The following align-equation gives an error:
\begin{align}
    \Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D} &= 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! error is cause by use of ampersands. try `\begin{align}
    {\Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D}} &= 0
\end{align}
` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solve the issue by simply adding braces in the definition of `\Mtrx`:

```
\newcommand{\Mtrx}[2][1]{{% <--- brace
    \ifx0#1
        \begin{matrix}  #2 \end{matrix}
    \else\ifx1#1
        \begin{bmatrix}  #2 \end{bmatrix}
    \else\ifx2#1
        \begin{pmatrix}  #2 \end{pmatrix}
    \fi\fi\fi
}} % <--- brace
```

However, here's how I'd do:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Mtrx}[2][]{%
  \begin{#1matrix} #2 \end{#1matrix}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \Mtrx[p]{A & B \\ C & D} = \Mtrx[b]{c\\d}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
    \Mtrx[p]{A & B \\ C & D} &= 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

If you really prefer numbers,

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Mtrx}[2][0]{%
  \begin{\mtrxtype{#1}matrix} #2 \end{\mtrxtype{#1}matrix}
}
\newcommand{\mtrxtype}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or b\or p\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D} = \Mtrx[1]{c\\d}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
    \Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D} &= 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

error is caused by use of ampersands. these from your new command had to be some how hidden from `align` ones. for example try

```
\begin{align}
{\Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D}} &= 0
\end{align}
```

or redefine your command as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Mtrx}[2][1]{
    \ifx 0#1
        {\begin{matrix}  #2 \end{matrix}}
    \else\ifx 1#1
        {\begin{bmatrix}  #2 \end{bmatrix}}
    \else\ifx 2#1
        {\begin{pmatrix}  #2 \end{pmatrix}}
    \fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}
% everything as expected here:
\begin{equation}
    \Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D} = \Mtrx[1]{c\\d}
\end{equation}

% The following align-equation gives an error: NOT ANYMORE
\begin{align}
    \Mtrx[2]{A & B \\ C & D} &= 0
\end{align}
```

[image]